# How to make iterable object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a javascript object like this

```js
let Lila = { 
  name: 'Lila', 
  height: `5'10"`,
  weight: 185
}
```

I want to iterate it  using `next()`

Comment: You can iterate through an object's keys using `Object.keys()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the answer

```
const Lila = {
    name: 'Lila',
    height: `5'10"`,
    weight: 185,
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        let index = 0; // use index to track properties 
        let properties = Object.keys(this); // get the properties of the object 
        let Done = false; // set to true when the loop is done 
        return { // return the next method, need for iterator 
            next: () => {
                Done = (index >= properties.length);
                // define the object you will return done state, value eg Lila ,key eg 
                //name
                let obj = {
                    done: Done,
                    value: this[properties[index]],
                    key: properties[index]
                };
                index++; // increment index
                return obj;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 14):

You could assign a [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) property to the object with an iterator.

Read more about the use of `iterator.next` in [iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).

```js
let lila = { name: 'Lila', height: '5\'10"', weight: 185 };

lila[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    var k;
    for (k in this) {
        yield [k, this[k]];
    }
};

var iterator = lila[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next()); // get the first of a sequence of values

console.log([...lila]);       // get all key/values pairs
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

why do you need an iterator or a generator? Keep it simple and just iterate over the object...

```
const lila = { name: 'Lila', height: '5\'10"', weight: 185 };

for (key in lila) { console.log(lila[key]) }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can [convert an object to an iterable (Array) with Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries)

```js
let Lila = {
  name: 'Lila',
  height: 5.10,
  weight: 185
};
let iterableLila = Object.entries(Lila);
console.log(iterableLila);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through an object's keys using Object.keys() and then just encapsulate it normally with an iterator function:

```
function makeIterator(obj) {
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let current_index = 0;

    return {
       next: function() {
           return current_index < keys.length ?
               {value: obj[keys[current_index++]], done: false} :
               {done: true};
       }
    };
}
```

then you can use it like that:

```
let Lila = { name: 'Lila', height:5'10",
    weight: 185}
let iterator = makeIterator(Lila)
console.log(iterator.next().value)
console.log(iterator.next().value)
console.log(iterator.next().value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try *following*:

```js
const lila = {
  name: "lila",
  height: "5'10",
  weight: 185,
  [Symbol.iterator] () {
    let step = 0;
    let properties = Object.keys(this); 
    return{ 
      next(){
        return{
          value: properties[step],
          done: step++ === properties.length
        }
      }
    }
  }
}for (let prop of lila){console.log(prop)}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).