# How to iterate over an object using Symbol.iterator?

Tags: javascript

```
let obj = {
  username: "Hello",
  age: 32,
  gender: "Male",
};

obj[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  let index = 0;
  let prop = Object.keys(this);
  return {
    next: () => {
      if (index >= prop.length) {
        return {
          value: that[prop[index]],
          key: prop[index],
          done: false,
        };
      } else {
        return { value: undefined, done: true };
      }
    },
  };
};

for (let i of obj) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Hi, I want to iterate over the object by using Symbol.iterator technique and display all the keys, but I'm not getting the desired output here.

Comment: What's the problem with `Object.keys()`?

Comment: Someone asked me this question in an interview.

Comment: Ah OK. Well where do you expect the "start" and "end" properties to come from? Properties in objects are not intrinsically numbered. I'm not sure how you'd do this without `Object.keys()` to get an array of property names to iterate through.

Comment: you could have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48132121/1447675